# changing status with same Controller in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I made a **StatusController** to change the status. I have **Banner** model and **Page** model.

My **StatusController** Looks like:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Banner;
use App\Page;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class StatusController extends Controller
{
    public function changeStatus($modelName, $id)
    {
        $model = $modelName::select('id','status')->whereId($id)->first();
        if($model->status == 1)
        {
            $model->status = 0;
        } else {
            $model->status = 1;
        }
        $model->update();
        $notification = [
            'message' => 'Updated Successfully!',
            'alert-type' => 'success'
        ];
        return back()->with($notification);

    }
}
```

My **Web.php** is :

```
Route::post('status/{modelName}/{status}', 'StatusController@changeStatus')->name('status');
```

My View looks Like this:

```
<form action="{{route('status',['model' => 'Page', 'status' => $page->id])}}" method="POST">
    {{csrf_field()}}
    <button title="Turn OFF" class="btn btn-xs btn-default">
    <i class="fa
     @if($page->status==1)
     status-active
     fa-toggle-on
     @else
     status-inactive
     fa-toggle-off
     @endif
     fa-2x"></i>
  </button>
```

I want to change my status when I click **status** icon. But when i click it. It shows an error.

```
FatalThrowableError in StatusController.php line 15:
Class 'Page' not found
```

When I tried dd($modelName) it shows **Page**. What's going wrong

Also, Please tell me if there is any other better idea to change status. For all my models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though you have the `use App\Page;` statement at the top, php will have issues calling functions on a class when all you have is the class string. `Page` is different from `'Page'`. Instead, you need to use [call_user_func](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php):

```
$model = call_user_func("App\\$modelName::select", ['id','status'])
    ->whereId($id)
    ->first();
```

Comment: It didn't worked. I shows the error: `call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'Page' not found`

Comment: You might need to include the namespace as well. I updated my answer.